# check pattern of HTTP GET using REGEXc#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to RegEx and having trouble getting pattern
have request with first line that look like

```
GET /someFolder/someSubfolder/someFile.fileExtenstion?param1=abc HTTP/1.1
```

I would like to check that the correct pattren exist 
meaning first word GET later some valid URL than HTTP/verison
What I have till now is

```
string input = line;
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"GET /([A-Za-z0-9-.+!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]])\ HTTP/1.1",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    string URL = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

But I get No match
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the regex a lot as

```
^GET.*HTTP\/1\.1$
```

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `.*` matches anything
- `$` anchors the regex at end of string. Ensures that nothing followes the matched string

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/uB8nI0/1)

Comment: Wow cool , thanks ! but what about checking the syntax of the URL ?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka is there any specific rule for the url? or is it just simple as /somefile/somefile/.....

Comment: I would like something to fit all url , but this will be fine as start , THank you

Answer (score 1):

Old question but it deserve new answer for anyone looking for correctly matching HTTP Start Line and extract values from it.

The (**.***) will not match white space, also escaping forward slash not necessary in **C#** and will lead to not match .

Here is sample code with named capturing group:

```
var httpRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<method>[a-zA-Z]+)\s(?<url>.+)\sHTTP/(?<major>\d)\.(?<minor>\d+)$");
var match = httpRegex.Match("GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
    $"Method: {match.Groups["method"].Value}\r\n" +
    $"Url: {match.Groups["url"].Value}\r\n" +
    $"httpVersion: HTTP/{match.Groups["major"].Value}.{match.Groups["minor"].Value}"
    );
}
```

Escaping forward slash required in languages like PHP and JavaScript, and here the same code for PHP with escaping https://regex101.com/r/2l7k83/1/